# Не могу отличить определение от сказуемого. Цельные, неделимые словосочетания!

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, определения

Предложение 1: "Эта девушка высокого роста".
Предложение 2: "Девочка трех лет".

Почему в первом предложении "высокого роста" - сказуемое, а во втором "трех лет" - определение? Эта трудность встретилась на сайте licey.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Эта девушка (была) высокого роста.** Двусоставное предложение: предмет и его признак, несогласованное определение является именной частью составного сказуемого.

2) **Девочка трех лет**. Односоставное назывное предложение, несогласованное определение.

А вообще говоря, **такие предложения должны даваться в контексте,** иначе разбор  носит условный характер, то есть ситуацию приходится додумывать.

Например:

Эта девушка высокого роста, вряд ли она занимается спортивной гимнастикой.

Девочка трех лет, маленькая, хрупкая. Стоит в сторонке, ни с кем не играет.

Comment: То есть все зависит от занчения словосочетания? И спасибо за ответ! )